# Java SQL syntax error trying to delete from jtable

Tags: java

i'm trying to delete selected row from jtable and database together but i'm getting syntax error. Might be cause i'm using varchar or really the syntax is just wrong in this case?

```
    btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Dzēst");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
                int tableRow = table_1.getSelectedRow();
                Object Kods = table_1.getValueAt(tableRow, 0);
                Object Nosaukums = table_1.getValueAt(tableRow, 1);
                Object Inventara = table_1.getValueAt(tableRow, 2);
                Object Uzskaites = table_1.getValueAt(tableRow, 3);
                Object Iegad = table_1.getValueAt(tableRow, 4);
                Statement stmt = null;
                Connection connection = ConnectDB();


                String sql = "DELETE FROM users " +
                       "WHERE Kods = " + Kods + " AND Nosaukums = '" + Nosaukums + "' AND Inventara Nr = " + 
                        Inventara  + " AND Uzskaites vertiba = '" + Uzskaites  + "' AND Iegades vertiba = " + Iegad;
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
               stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(dddddddd.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nav ievadita visa informacija");
            }
```

ERROR:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Nr = ttttt AND Uzskaites vertiba = '3.0' AND Iegades vertiba = 3.0' at line 1
```

Database variables:

```
Kods -Index -int(255)       
Nosaukums - varchar(255)         
Inventara Nr - varchar(255)  
Uzskaites vertiba - float                
Iegades vertiba - float
```

Comment: I'd also recommend you have a look at `PreparedStatement`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your columns have space-separated names. Normally it isn't best-practice to use such a naming convention, but snake_case or CamelCase.

In your case, you need to properly quote your column names, e.g.

```
WHERE `Inventara Nr` = '33'
```

Be aware though that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. I recommend reading about them. You should always use [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: Thanks, will keep in note. Did change everything with snake_case but now there is new error. Unknown column 'ttetetetetete' in 'where clause'.

Comment: @Krichukzz Everything character like has to be put in quotes as well. Example:   DELETE FROM docs WHERE content = 'Hello World'. But as mentioned, PreparedStatements will do that for you when using setString for your parameter. In your case 'Inventara Nr' was indeed a varchar, so it should be WHERE 'Inventara Nr' = 'ttetetetetete'. This might help you using PreparedStatements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: `String sql = "DELETE FROM users " +
                     "WHERE Kods = " + Kods + " AND Nosaukums = '" + Nosaukums + "' AND Inventara_Nr = '" + 
                      Inventara  + "' AND Uzskaites_vertiba = " + Uzskaites  + " AND Iegades_vertiba = " + Iegad;
              stmt = connection.createStatement();
             stmt.executeUpdate(sql); ` Still does not want to delete anything. Even if i put 'Nosaukums' and 'Inventara_Nr' in quoutes.

Comment: Can you put a System.out.println(sql) right after you assigned it?

Comment: DELETE FROM users WHERE `Kods` = 6 AND `Nosaukums` = 'Zirgs' AND `Inventara_Nr` = 'ZirgsTT' AND `Uzskaites_vertiba` = 65.66 AND `Iegades_vertiba` = 4444.4

Comment: There is none, i can delete selected row when i enter int value for example 1/2/3/4 but when i enter float value 1.1/2.2 it just does not delete.

Comment: Yes, if i change float to double/decimal it lets me delete anything i want but when its float it does not delete. @petul

Comment: EDIT: Well i did go around it by putting DECIMAL(11,2) in database.

Comment: @Krichukzz Oh yeah, floating-point values cause some problems indeed. Decimal is a wise choice